# HMACSHA1 signature generates different signature in Java and C# code

Tags: java

Java:

```
SecretKeySpec signingKey = new SecretKeySpec(secretKey.getBytes(),HMAC_SHA1_ALGORITHM);

Mac mac = Mac.getInstance(HMAC_SHA1_ALGORITHM); mac.init(signingKey);

byte[] bytes = mac.doFinal(signatureString.getBytes()); return BASE64.encodeBAse64String(bytes);
```

C#:

```
public string GenerateSignature(Uri url, string consumerKey, string consumerSecret, string token, string tokenSecret, string httpMethod, string timeStamp, string nonce, signatureTypes signatureType, out string normalizedUrl, out string normalizedRequestParameters) {

 string signatureBase = GenerateSignatureBase(url, consumerKey, token, tokenSecret, httpMethod, timeStamp, nonce, HMACSHA1SignatureType, out normalizedUrl, out normalizedRequestParameters);

 HMACSHA1 hmacsha1 = new HMACSHA1();

 hmacsha1.key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(string.Format("{0} & {1}", UrlEncode(consumerSecret), string.IsNullEmpty(tokenSecret) ? "" : UrlEncode(tokenSecret)));

 //data is generated signature base string with attaching all parameters.

 byte[] dataBuffer = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);
 byte[] hashBytes = hashAlgorithm.ComputeHash(dataBuffer);
 return Convert.ToBase64String(hashBytes);
}
```

I am creating REST services where I am using OAuth 1.0 signature and for generating Oauth I need to use HMACSHA1 algorithm. My client's API is in C# and my API is in Java, and I have to generate a signature that should be encrypted by my client successfully.

Comment: My first guess would be a problem converting String to byte[]. On Java you use the platform charset (UTF-8 or ISO88591, ...), on C# you use ASCII encoding.

Comment: yes i have used that also.but still it is not working

Comment: and also i am using same encoding method in java which is using by C# vendor.

Comment: protected final String UrlEncode(String value)
{
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
char ch[]=new char[value.length()];
for (int i = 0; i < value.length(); i++) {
 ch[i]=value.charAt(i);
}
for (char symbol : ch)
{
if (unreservedChars.indexOf(symbol) != -1)
{
result.append(symbol);
}
else
{
result.append('%' + String.format("%02X",(int)symbol));
}
}
return result.toString();
}

Comment: It may be unpopular but hex dump the input and output of each. Also verify with [HMAC calc](http://extranet.cryptomathic.com/hmaccalc/index) by Cryptomathic.

Comment: @rishabh keshari 1992: Do not post code in a comments, it ends up unreadable. Edit your question instead and add the relevant information.

Comment: Thanks for giving me your valuable time, i got same signature. here is problem in my encoding logic only. which i have used to encode the parameters and the URL and secret key. i changed and i got.